# Android Device doesn't have a Clock app

Tags: clock

So, here is my problem: One time, I am setting an alarm, but I noticed that my phone doesn't have a stocked Clock app. I also go to `/system/app/ClockPackage_ESS.apk` using ES File Explorer. I installed that .apk, but when I'm trying to install it, it says "File not installed."

Here is the screenshot (click to enlarge) of the App Drawer:

[image: App Drawer]

Also, here's the device information:

> `Device Information:
>   Samsung Galaxy Core Prime
>   Model number: SM-G360HU
>   Android version: 4.4.4 (Kitkat)
>   Baseband version: G360HUXXU0ANL6
>   Kernel version:
>      3.10.17-388893
>      dpi@SWDD6214 #2
>      Thu Feb 5 16:44:31 KST 2015
>   Build number: KTU84P.G360HUXXU0AOB1`

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxlogix.clock&hl=en

Comment: Thanks, @Lucky! This Clock app was much better than the stocked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phone does have clock if there's that app inside system/app as you told. Its not necessary that it must be shown on launcher, though normally clock apps are shown. I suggest you give a try to some third party launcher on store and see if that does some trick. On contrary, you should be able to access clock by tapping the clock in notification panel.

Also, if there's some app inside system/app, its already installed. And apps inside this folder are called `system apps`. You cant install them like normal apps by simply tapping and pressing on install (or rather they dont need to be installed like normal). You install them by simply pushing their apk file to system/app or system/priv-app depending on type of app and then setting their permission to 755 or rw-r-r with some file manager. So that "install failed" is justified. In other words, app is already installed.

Comment: Thanks, @JaskaranbirS. I have installed CM Launcher from Google Play Store, and still the Clock app was not there. I also searched "Clock" on the Local Apps/Web, and it has no results. Also, as you said, if I tap Clock on the Notification Panel, it just go to the Date & Time Settings.

Comment: Then its the way clock app is made mate. You can either install third party clock app from store or use it from notification panel. There are ways that might force it to show on launcher by decompiling it and editing manifest. But its kinda not worth the trouble. Anyway, if my answer solved your query then you should mark it as solved for future reference :)

Comment: What's the correct permission to set?  You've mentioned two different permissions, `755` and `rw- r-- r--`.  `755` is equivalent to `rwx r-x r-x`, whereas `rw- r-- r--` is equivalent to `644`.  Click [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39710/how-to-get-permission-number-by-string-rw-r-r/39712#39712) to learn more about Android permissions.